# How to use pattern matching in F# in a way that i can convert ["a";"b";"c";"a";"d";"e"] into ["a b c a";"d";"e"]

Tags: list, f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching, functional-testing

I have a string list like ["a";"b";"c";"a","d","e"] and i want to know how can a make that string list like ["a b c a";"d";"e"] y try with pattern matching but i get too many problems:

```
  let rec modifyString lista  =
  match lista with
  |[] -> []
  //try to get the place where my string start  
  |head::tail when head = "a" ->
    let tryHard = helperString tail
    tryHard
// try to pass a list that is not with 'a'    
  |primero::segundo ->
        [primero] :: modifyString segundo

  // Try to get de tail list that i know is after "a" 
  let rec helperString lista =
   match lista with
   |[] -> []
   |head::tail when tail.Head <> string '"' ->
     let aux = head + " "
     let aux2 = head :: helperString tail
     aux2
```

Now i almost have solution this the problem now is that when given something like this [a b c d e " e f g " h i j] (think is a string list where every element is a string) the output is ["a";"b";"c";"d";"ef"; "g";""";"h";"i";"j"][] the code is the next:

```
let rec helperString lista =
  match lista with
  |head::tail when tail.Head = string '"' ->
    head + tail.Head::tail.Tail
  |head::tail when tail.Head <> string '"' ->
    let aux = helperString tail
    head + tail.Head :: tail.Tail

let rec modifyString listab  =
  match listab with
  |[] -> []
  |head::tail when tail.Head <> string '"' ->
    head :: modifyString tail
  |head::tail when tail.Head = string '"' ->
      helperString tail.Tail
```

Comment: It is not handled with |[] -> []? I assume that passing the tail will in a moment be a empty list [] but since im not using the whole list  only a some elements from the list should I not use |[] -> []?

Comment: sorry, its this one: `|head::tail when tail.Head <> string '"'` - what happens when ` tail.Head == "`

Comment: Try to improve something i dont know if im going in the rigth way .....

Comment: So now, you have run into a limitation where the compiler isn't too clever - just remove the when from `
  |head::tail when tail.Head = string '"' ->`

Comment: What's the specification of your algorithm? Concat the first four strings? Concat all the strings until you find one which is equal to the first one? Concat all the strings until you stumble upon a repetition?

Comment: Its so i can use each word as token and one of the tokens is a string. I wanted to try with pattern matching and some types to learn more about that.

Comment: My only problem now is that the string at the end is like "efg""

Comment: By the way thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally get how to do this task just in the last update of the code USE the var aux .

```
let rec helperString lista =
  match lista with
  |head::tail when tail.Head = string '"' ->
    head + tail.Head::tail.Tail
  |head::tail when tail.Head <> string '"' ->
    let aux = helperString tail
    head + aux.Head :: aux.Tail

let rec modifyString listab  =
  match listab with
  |[] -> []
  |head::tail when tail.Head <> string '"' ->
    head :: modifyString tail
  |head::tail when tail.Head = string '"' ->
      helperString tail.Tail
```